# Stack Overflow Android application to answer questions

Tags: support, app-request

I am a regular answerer on Stack Overflow, and I have been trying to use my Android phone for my workflow, but unfortunately the mobile Web application is very cumbersome to use: for example, the answer/comment box often gets obscured by the on-screen keyboard, so I don't see what I type.

Is there any offering of an app specifically geared towards answerers? It is easy to find various read-only apps, but I have so far been unable to find something good for my use case.

Comment: Related: [Is there any official Stack Overflow Android app?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/182709)

Comment: I'd recommend [posting about the issues](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?tags=mobile%20bug%20design) you have with the mobile web interface on Meta Stack Overflow, by the way.